# How to find the percolation path?

Tags: r, matlab

I have a dataset of **`x`**, **`y`**, **`z`** and **`size`** of some dots in a cubic rectangle ( dimensions of 500*250*4.4 ).

I'd like to know how can I show graphically if there is any percolation path from upper surface to the lower one either in MATLAB or R?

( by percolation path I mean the minimum length bond that connects overlapping or connected dots together from the upper surface to the lower one )

---

Here is the data:

```
    x           y             z         size      time
209.209774  7.9408097   2.319656267 0.793087629 2.349739533
209.517228  7.7415856   3.106089673 0.855368535 3.328208366
209.825582  8.3846153   4.4         0.963765604 3.427967029
209.394164  7.3352438   2.237668673 0.793192695 3.796507832
209.63978   7.8792626   3.27099508  0.900599771 4.080787149
209.568834  7.8546372   2.132928776 0.706479048 4.976109131
128.111097  2.320084    1.009058449 0.84575615  5.009483351
128.828759  3.0712943   2.203492827 0.801342486 6.86730518
130.167194  3.1545389   0.447034036 0.710835683 7.899154944
128.079092  2.9857334   1.172837724 0.938893977 8.958792166
128.168961  3.1109508   1.59741468  0.828790284 9.601263
126.428196  1.2431261   4.4         0.841620207 10.28888122
169.000926  232.3168799 2.838484773 0.965162937 14.44635033
167.613178  233.0870048 4.4         0.963311412 17.31717175
168.280608  232.7597414 2.986730293 0.935770919 18.75617743
169.515323  232.2533107 1.903419973 0.832796506 18.97671994
169.0959    232.8055114 1.849872924 0.963380767 20.05274055
169.360326  232.178669  3.254741781 0.798400142 21.72085676
316.914311  85.1429799  0.304532208 0.874779903 21.82851836
317.666683  84.3638348  0.575424986 0.897444099 23.44320468
317.843483  84.3204013  0.649951435 0.819952123 31.73428955
316.411077  85.2226315  1.208328587 0.909955711 32.665324
315.528734  84.5738727  0           0.803030253 39.84755565
316.95075   85.9984237  0           0.846629661 43.03680485
473.066628  144.3695194 3.692835902 0.708103992 44.77448685
472.511676  144.642549  2.703160589 0.727135968 46.00986403
471.789029  145.1873901 4.4         0.793700934 46.10006721
473.124093  144.6244314 3.748699545 0.923879276 46.67709969
473.007353  144.4490594 3.822257434 0.813995533 47.13577935
474.160461  144.3467013 0.667543933 0.768687855 49.28275368
401.928394  143.4728223 1.709059908 0.82799731  49.83156299
401.536748  144.5209801 1.3955402   0.875955905 50.6172275
401.827267  144.5965744 0           0.84700354  53.46835651
402.338068  143.7885394 3.346277835 0.825995466 56.55046007
401.669496  144.1486653 4.4         0.854163065 58.68959416
401.616204  144.0842306 2.146882026 0.829120948 59.26343762
403.357177  71.4047311  3.236605073 0.936593234 59.89403416
402.618287  71.1964819  2.413086339 0.732318033 60.23297696
403.453695  71.4333441  2.520175374 0.729361398 62.50977251
403.21512   71.8066027  3.401890159 0.861805672 65.57455915
404.556463  71.2015514  2.526535007 0.952867407 66.72056939
403.646341  71.4315758  2.430139247 0.972378323 67.01929229
102.114416  68.5545694  2.506939095 0.834796995 70.27866664
106.483907  68.6162716  0.753957696 0.894386379 70.83871434
```

This is how I can plot it in R:

```
library(rgl)
library (graphics)
library(grDevices)
library(plotrix)
x <- read.table(file.choose(), sep=",", header=T )
y <- x[,1:3]
spheres3d(y, radius=15*(x$size), alpha=1)
```

Comment: I can see how to do it in R using various distance and graph calculations. For a start you could plot the data in R using the rgl package and spheres3d functions...

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for the comment. I added the code for plotting the data in the question.

Comment: Why do you multiply your size by 15? The spheres aren't that big are they?

Comment: That's because you have a very thin flat volume, **not** a cube. Try adding axes with `axis3d("x");axis3d("y");axis3d("z");box3d()` and you might see what's happening. The plot has to be thin like that otherwise the spheres wouldn't be truly spherical...

Comment: @Spacedman could you please tell me how can I ask the code to print the data values (x,y,z,time.size) for the vertices of the path? (after get.shortest.paths())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (with data loaded into `d`):

```
# compute xyz pythagorean distance between all points as a full matrix:
dd = dist(d[,c("x","y","z")])
ddm = as.matrix(dd)

# compute similar matrix based on sum of object sizes (assumes size is radius)
drad = outer(d$size, d$size, "+")

# compute overlap matrix as any pairs of points closer than sum of their radii
dadj = (ddm<=drad)

# and convert to a graph object
require(igraph)
dg = graph.adjacency(dadj, mode="undirected")

# all objects at the top have z-size less than 0
starts = which(d$z-d$size < 0)
# objects at bottom have z+size greater than 4.4
ends = which(d$z+d$size > 4.4)

# now try and find paths:
range(shortest.paths(dg, starts, ends))
[1] Inf Inf
```

That means no paths were found.

If you try again with double the size, ie replace one line above with:

```
# double the size:
drad = outer(2*d$size, 2*d$size, "+")
```

Then:

```
range(shortest.paths(dg, starts, ends))
[1]   1 Inf
```

which means there is at least one path between objects at the top and the bottom.

```
> which(shortest.paths(dg, starts, ends)<Inf, arr.ind=TRUE)
    row col
24    5   3
133  24  16
133  24  17
```

This tells us there's three paths, starting at `starts[5]`, `starts[24]`, and `starts[24]`, and finishing respectively at `ends[3]`, `ends[16]`, and `ends[17]`. Further igraph functions will show you the path:

```
> get.shortest.paths(dg, starts[5], ends[3] )$vpath
[[1]]
[1] 24 26

> get.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[16] )$vpath
[[1]]
[1] 133 150 151

> get.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[17] )$vpath
[[1]]
[1] 133 150 153
```

The returned numbers are the indexes in the data of the points traversed along the path. So:

```
d[get.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[17] )$vpath[[1]],]
           x        y         z      size
133 324.8932 146.4365 0.8823413 0.9670826
150 325.3532 143.7297 2.9670642 0.9871330
153 325.8101 144.3565 4.3900869 0.9981148
```

Note that there may be more than one path from `starts[24]` to `ends[17]`. The `get.shortest.paths` function only returns one for our start/finish points. To see them all:

```
> get.all.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[17] )
$res
$res[[1]]
[1] 133 152 153

$res[[2]]
[1] 133 150 153
[...]
```

This shows us there are two routes, via 152 or 150. The points for these two routes are then:

```
> d[get.all.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[17] )$res[[1]],]
           x        y         z      size
133 324.8932 146.4365 0.8823413 0.9670826
152 325.9366 144.5316 2.3215717 0.8693740
153 325.8101 144.3565 4.3900869 0.9981148
> d[get.all.shortest.paths(dg, starts[24], ends[17] )$res[[2]],]
           x        y         z      size
133 324.8932 146.4365 0.8823413 0.9670826
150 325.3532 143.7297 2.9670642 0.9871330
153 325.8101 144.3565 4.3900869 0.9981148
```

Which makes me think - the "shortest route" is counted as the smallest number of steps between points, and does not take into account the size. So a long route composed of ten points is "shorter" than a shorter-distance route composed of 11 points. Your original question was about whether there was any percolation, so I didn't really think about finding the smallest path in any sense, just whether a path existed.

It should be possible to construct the graph with edges weighted by the sum of the size of the points, and then find shortest paths that way...

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have a question. For another dataset I tried this code and it gives me: [1] 4 Inf but when I want to show the four shortest path it just shows me : row col 33 8 8 What might cause this problem? I can put the dataset file if needed.

Comment: The range function tells you there's at least one path of length four, and no shorter ones. The which has a row for each possible path, in this case it looks like there's one part from 8 to 8 which is a bit odd. Can you add the data?

Comment: I found the reason of error. Just as the last question, could you please tell me how can I ask it to print the data values (x,y,z,time.size) for the vertices of the path? (after get.shortest.paths()) @Spacedman

Comment: Have edited to show how to get the data values of the path - they are just the numbered rows of the data input.

Comment: I really appreciate it.